# Codecademy supermarket "subtract" error

Tags: python

I have started programming in Python at Codecademy, and I have a problem:

Make the following changes to your compute_bill function:

1. While you loop through each item of food, only add the price of the item to total if the item's stock count is greater than zero.
2. If the item is in stock and after you add the price to the total, subtract one from the item's stock count."

My code reads:

```
shopping_list = ["banana", "orange", "apple"]

stock = {
    "banana": 6,
    "apple": 0,
    "orange": 32,
    "pear": 15
}

prices = {
    "banana": 4,
    "apple": 2,
    "orange": 1.5,
    "pear": 3
}

def compute_bill(food):
    total = 0
    for each in food:
        if stock[each] > 0:
            total += prices[each]
            stock[each] -= 1
    return total

food = ["banana", "orange", "apple"]
compute_bill(food)
```

I have this error

> Oops, try again. stock doesn't look quite right! Make sure to not call `compute_bill` since it changes the stock! It should contain: {'orange': 32, 'pear': 15, 'banana': 6, 'apple': 0}

I don't understand why there is a problem.

Comment: "Make sure to not call `compute_bill` since it changes the stock!"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message says

> Make sure to not call `compute_bill`...

But your code includes:

```
compute_bill(food)
```

Remove that line.

Answer (score 0):

All you simply have to do is get rid of it. If you want to check, this is my code. I have finished Codecademy.

```
shopping_list = ["banana", "orange", "apple"]

stock = {
    "banana": 6,
    "apple": 0,
    "orange": 32,
    "pear": 15
}

prices = {
     "banana": 4,
     "apple": 2,
     "orange": 1.5,
     "pear": 3
}

# Write your code below!
def compute_bill(food):
    total = 0
    for item in food:
    return total
        total += prices[item]
```

Judging by your code, it is exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
def compute_bill(food):
    total = 0
    for each in food:
        if stock[each] > 0:
            total = prices[each] + total
            stock[each] -= 1
    return total
```

Answer (score -1):

Guys the stock value for each of the values in the calling function.
Like This

```
shopping_list = ["banana", "orange", "apple"]
stock = {
"banana": 7,
"apple": 1,
"orange": 33,
"pear": 15
}
```